# How to get the textbox value when its corresponding checkboxes are ticked?

Tags: php, html

When a user ticks a checkbox and enters data into the corresponding textbox and submits, I want to show a form which will display the textbox values which checkboxes were ticked

Answer (score 4):

Have you considered trying a tutorial and seeing how that works?

http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/php/php4p11.html